# Django Rest Framework: how to access single API elements in URL?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to access every API element by URL like this "/api/v1/element_id"

I have explicitly defined the pk in serializers

serializers.py

```
class TweetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tweet_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('tweet_id', 'author', 'text', 'created_at', 'retweet_count', 'favourite_count',)
        model = Tweet
```

But it does not work. I get Not found error

models.py

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    #tweet_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tweet_id = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    retweet_count = models.IntegerField()
    favourite_count = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tweet_id)
```

views.py

```
class TweetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Tweet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TweetSerializer


class TweetDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Tweet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TweetSerializer
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', TweetDetail.as_view()),
    path('', TweetList.as_view()),
]
```

Listing all tweets works fine, /api/v1/, but single tweet is not returned.

I have tried to set a ForeignKey in the models but then I get an error column tweet_id_id not found.

Comment: You should access the detail API by `/api/v1/1234/` where `1234` is your PK of `Tweet` instance

Comment: Yeah I know, it does not work however

Comment: What you have got btw?

Comment: As I already stated in my question, the listing works fine, also all tweets by /api/v1/
But accessing the single element /api/v1/1234 returns Not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally need to add a `lookup_field` to `view` if you wish to retrieve a particular object.

So in this scenario, your `lookup_field` is `tweet_id`

Your view becomes

```
class TweetDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Tweet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TweetSerializer
    lookup_field = 'tweet_id'
```

Then you reference same `lookup_field` in your `url`. So your `url` becomes

```
path('<tweet_id>', TweetDetail.as_view()),
```